# Windows Phone 8 Font (Quartz MS) only working in Designer

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, font-family

i currently try to use the Font "Quartz MS" which was a given Font in my Fontlist (Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate) - In the designer everything looks awesome - but when I run the app on my device it doesn't load that font (Standard Font used)

Can you help me?

(Tested on Lumia 820)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full list of supported fonts on the Windows Phone (that come with the device): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202920%28v=vs.105%29.aspx.

For any additional font you want to use, you need to manually add it to the phone, see http://jeffblankenburgdotcom.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-24-embedding-fonts/.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer - however, I do not get this working - I downloaded the font inserted it - copy always - content is set and I can even chose it from the list now - it says "added to the projekt" on mouseover. Still not working on my phone...

Answer (score 0):

After adding the font file in the project and setting build action to content, reference it in your XAML as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello!!"  FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/BlahBlah.ttf#BlahBlah" />
```

NB: PLEASE NOTE, [Font name].ttf#[Font name]

Comment: Thank you, but as mentioned to the post commend before it does not work